# Simplest way to control the speed of 4 identical fans

Tags: voltage-regulator, fan, motor-controller

Hi, my computer has 4 fans in it running on 12v from the PSU.

How can I control their speed?

Maybe a potentiometer?

Comment: Is it psu or cpu?  further are these powered externally from usb???

Comment: A computer atx power suplie, no there power from the molex connectors on the psu

Comment: Yes you are right just using any resistor in parallel will help.However for which resistor, stevenh can answer quite better.:)

Comment: An on/off-switch? Could you give us a bit more detail on what you want to accomplish?

Comment: No like making the fans slower/quiter then being able to turn them up to full power ha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As peril brain already pointed out in the comments, a simple resistor in series is the easiest solution.

Note however, that speed regulation with a resistor is poor if you want to achieve very low speeds: fans require more voltage to start turning than to keep turning. (They need to overcome static friction.)

Most intelligent fan controllers therefore start up the fan with a "burst" of higher voltage and then reduce the voltage. Obviously this in not something you can do with a simple resistor.

I had fans that could not be made to turn slower than half speed with a simple resistor. Else they would not start. With others this was no issue at all. It really depends on how much friction your fan has.

Comment: Ok I understand, half speed to full speed would be fine for for me, but how could I control the speed like turn it up and down?

Comment: @lewisdenny If you want to constantly change it, maybe a potentiometer would be a good choice. You could allow it to have the burst manually by dropping the pot to zero, and then adjust it to whatever speed you prefer. It's a brute force solution, with the main advantage being simplicity.

Comment: @lewisdenny As an alternative to the potentiometer you could also make the control automatic using a temperature-dependent resistor. Keyword: "NTC" (negative temperature coefficient) These components have less resistance when they are hotter which can be used to make the fan speed up when it gets hotter.

Comment: You need to take into account the power the fan uses, just putting **a resistor** in series with the fan is not the whole story, you should work out if the resistor can take the power it will be dissipating. Most potentiometers are not rated to take any power, you're better using one to control a basic PWM circuit... but really, for the $5 it would cost, you're better off just buying a controller from eBay and plugging it in.

Answer (score 1):

There are [many](http://www.quietpcusa.com/Fan-Speed-Controllers-C7.aspx) off-the-shelf fan speed controller modules available for PCs. They contain the logic to do the controlling for you, you simply plug your fans into it and away you go.